# Python - for loop ignoring if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a Python program that will print out the lyrics of 99 Bottles of Beer in chunks, which I've gotten to work. However, I need the last line to say "1 bottle of beer" as opposed to "1 bottle**s** of beer".

I wrapped my code in an if statement, but it appears the if statement is getting ignored. What am I doing wrong?

```
verse = '''
{some} bottles of beer on the wall
{some} bottles of beer
Take one down, pass it around
{less} bottles of beer on the wall
'''

verse2 = '''
{some} bottles of beer on the wall
{some} bottles of beer
Take one down, pass it around
1 bottle of beer on the wall
'''

for bottles in range(99 , 1, -1):
  if bottles >= 2:
    print(verse.format(some = bottles, less = bottles - 1))
  else:
    print(verse2.format(some = bottles))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranges don't include the endpoint, so the final element of your range is not 1 but 2.

Should you change the if-statement to `if bottles > 2:` instead, the output will be correct.

Comment: Sure enough, that also did the trick. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print(list(range(99 , 1, -1)))
```

The result should be:

```
[99, 98, 97, ..., 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Number 1 never appeared.

To Fix this issue, simply changing `range(99, 1, -1)` to `range(99, 0, -1)`.

Comment: Ahhh, I can't believe I missed that, that's exactly it. Thank you for being my second pair of eyes!